# very strange thing - Jetty in Ubuntu "Error 404 Not Found"

Tags: jetty, http-status-code-404

I installed the Jetty server in Ubuntu under /home/myUserName/jetty folder, and I wanted to try the hello world. There was a very very strange problem happened.

Because I used the ssh in terminal to connect the remote ubuntu server, after I started the jetty, I can access http://localhost:8080/hello, but when I closed the terminal, I can't access http://localhost:8080/hello, I got the message "Error 404 Not Found", but the jetty server was running. The problem is that the jetty only seems to work when I use the terminal to connect the remote ubuntu server.

Is there anyone having the same problem before? Thank you very much, if you can tell me your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are seeing is typical for how you started jetty.

You'll want to start jetty in a way that a terminal is not needed.

Try a simple background task first ...

```
$ java -jar start.jar 2>&1 > jetty.log &
```

or for a more advanced technique ...

```
$ nohup java -jar start.jar
```

these will both not require a terminal to keep running.